# How do I work with multiple git branches of a python module?

Tags: python, git, module

I want to use git to allow me to work on several features in a module I'm writing concurrently. I'm currently using SVN, with only one workspace, so I just have the workspace on my PYTHONPATH. I'm realizing this is less than ideal, so I was wondering if anyone could suggest a more 'proper' way of doing this.

Let me elaborate with a hypothetical situation:
I say I have a module 'eggs', with sub-modules 'foo' and 'bar'. Components in 'bar' use code in foo, so eggs/bar/a.py may 'import eggs.foo'.

Say that 'eggs' is in a git repository. I want to try out some changes to 'foo', so I copy it. The problem is that 'import eggs.foo' in eggs/bar finds the original repository in the PYTHONPATH, so it ends up using the old 'foo' instead of my modified one.

How do I set myself up such that each copy of the module uses its own associated 'foo'? Thanks.

edit- Thanks for the pointer to relative imports. I've read up on it and I can see how to apply it. One problem I'd have with using it is that I've built up a fairly large codebase, and I haven't been too neat about it so most modules have a  quick 'self-test' under `if __name__ == '__main__':`, which from what I've read does not play with relative imports:

- http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-October/408945.html
- http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t502905-relative-import-broken.html

The other solution I've been able to google up is to deliberately manipulate sys.path, which seems like an even worse hack. Are there any other possibilities?

edit - Thanks for the suggestions. I'd originally misunderstood git branches, so as pointed out branches are exactly what I want. Nonetheless, I hadn't heard of relative imports before so thanks for that as well. I've learnt something new and may incorporate its use.

Comment: Take a look at related questions (on the right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding correctly, but it seems that git would *be* the solution here, since git's branches don't need separate paths.

Create a branch for each working version of your eggs module. Then when you checkout that branch, the entire module is changed to a state matching the version of your sub-module. You could then merge what you need back and forth between the branches.

And as S.Lott pointed out, may a little refactoring couldn't hurt either ;)

Comment: I'm new to git so I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting. The problem is that if I have two branches checked out, submodules from the first will always be found first. Do you have a way around this? I will look at refactoring this.

Comment: My inexperience with git shows. I'd been branching by simply copying the repository, but you are indeed right. Git branches do do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3):

[Relative imports](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/tut/node8.html#SECTION008420000000000000000) ([PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)) might help:

```
eggs/
  __init__.py
  foo.py
  bar.py

# foo.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import bar
```

See [How do you organize Python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171785/how-do-you-organize-python-modules) for other options.

EDIT:

Yet another option is to use S.Lott's and Jim's suggestions i.e, restructure your package to factor out a `eggs.foo` part used by `eggs.bar.a` and use `git` to work on experimental branches (see [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/)).

Here's an example:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

[just to make sure that all is good]

```
$ git checkout -b experimental
Switched to a new branch "experimental"
```

[work on experimental stuff]

```
$ git commit -a
```

[commit to experimental branch]

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch "master"
```

[work on master branch]

```
$ git commit -a
```

To merge changes into master branch:

```
$ git merge experimental
```

See chapter [Basic Branching and Merging](http://book.git-scm.com/3_basic_branching_and_merging.html) from the above book.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have asked a related follow-up question, if you'd be so kind as to have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345746/refactoring-python-module-configuration-to-avoid-relative-imports

Answer (score 1):

"say I have a module 'eggs', with sub-modules 'foo' and 'bar'. Components in 'bar' use code in foo, so eggs/bar/a.py may 'import eggs.foo'."

This may not be the best structure.  I suggest you have some other modules struggling to get out.

You have `eggs.bar.a` depending on `eggs.foo`.  I'm guessing other stuff on `eggs` depends on `eggs.foo`.  Further, I suspect that `eggs.foo` could be partitioned into `eggs.foo` and `eggs.quux` and things might be simpler.

I'd recommend refactoring this to get a better structure.  The `PYTHONPATH` issues are symptomatic of too many things in the wrong places in the module tree.

Comment: Refactoring the code-in-common into eggs.quux doesn't solve the problem though. If I'm working on two copies of the module, even if I put both in PYTHONPATH, one will always come first, so the second eggs.bar.a still effectively uses the first's eggs.quux.

Comment: The point is to avoid 2 copies of the common module.  One copy, separated from other things.