# Refactoring python module configuration to avoid relative imports

Tags: python, configuration, module

This is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343517/how-do-i-work-with-multiple-git-branches-of-a-python-module) of mine.

I understand how to store and read configuration files. There are choices such as [ConfigParser](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-ConfigParser.html) and [ConfigObj](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html).

Consider this structure for a hypothetical 'eggs' module:

```
eggs/
  common/
    __init__.py
    config.py
  foo/
    __init__.py
    a.py
```

'eggs.foo.a' needs some configuration information. What I am currently doing is, in 'a',

```
import eggs.common.config
```

. One problem with this is that if 'a' is moved to a deeper level in the module tree, the relative imports break. Absolute imports don't, but they require your module to be on your PYTHONPATH.

A possible alternative to the above absolute import is a relative import. Thus, in 'a',

```
import .common.config
```

Without debating the merits of relative vs absolute imports, I was wondering about other possible solutions?

edit- Removed the VCS context

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171785/how-do-you-organize-python-modules

Answer (score 2):

"imports ... require your module to be on your PYTHONPATH"

Right.

So, what's wrong with setting `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: If you have more than one set of files under development at the same time (e.g. multiple branches), it makes it harder to switch from one to the other if you need to change the PYTHONPATH each time; plus, it adds a dependency that requires some work to get under version control.

Answer (score 0):

require statement from [pkg_resources](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#basic-workingset-methods) maybe what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it from this and previous questions you only need one path to be in `sys.path`. If we are talking about `git` as VCS (mentioned in previous question) when only one branch is checked out at any time (single working directory). You can switch, merge branches as frequently as you like.

Comment: I've removed the VCS context as I realized it wasn't really relevant to my question. Switching VCS just ended up exposing this particular design question to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of something along the lines of a more 'push-based' kind of solution. Instead of importing the shared objects (be they for configuration, or utility functions of some sort), have the top-level **init** export it, and each intermediate **init** import it from the layer above, and immediately re-export it.

I'm not sure if I've got the python terminology right, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Like this, any module that needs to use the shared object(which in the context of this example represents configuration information) simply imports it from the **init** at its own level.

Does this sound sensible/feasible?

Answer (score 0):

You can trick the import mechanism, by adding each subdirectory to `egg/__init__.py`:

```
__path__.append(__path__[0]+"\\common")
__path__.append(__path__[0]+"\\foo")
```

then, you simply import all modules from the egg namespace; e.g. `import egg.bar` (provided you have file egg/foo/bar.py).
Note that foo and common should not be a package - in other words, they should not contain `__init__.py` file.

This solution completely solves the issue of eventually moving files around; however it flattens the namespace and therefore it may not be as good, especially in big projects - personally, I prefer full name resolution.