# Python Pandas Dataframe Memory error when there is enough memroy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[image]

Exception has occurred: MemoryError Unable to allocate 34.6 MiB for an array with shape (2265257,) and data type complex128

[image]

Hello, I have encountered this error. But I can't understand why this kind of error occurs.

I know that It is raised due to lack of memory.

But I have enough memory to handle that data.

Do you know why Python limits it even when I have more memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the 32 bit version of python. On Microsoft Windows, 32 bit processes can only utilize 2 GB of 4 GB maximum possible memory and your Python process is near the limit. I suggest using the 64 bit version.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
Is there any way to unlimit that?

Comment: I have to use this cuz of one middleware

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot overcome the architectural limit. But maybe you can analyze and optimize your code in terms of memory consumption.

In this thread you can find some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002247/how-to-reduce-python-script-memory-usage
Maybe you can give the Python memory-profiler a try. https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/