# Python Pandas Dataframe Memory error when there is enough memory

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python 3.8 64-bit with Pycharm on windows 8. I got a memory error when trying to make a dataframe from a list.

What I'm trying to do is to read a huge .csv (25gb) into a list using the `csv` package, make a dataframe with it using `pd.Dataframe`, and then export a .dta file with the `pd.to_stata` function. My RAM is 64gb, way larger than the data.

Here is the error msg:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 25.8 GiB for an array with shape (77058858, 45) and data type object
```

I found three similar questions but none of them work for me.

1. [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61698886/python-pandas-dataframe-memory-error-when-there-is-enough-memroy): the solution does not work for me because I am using 64-bit python.
2. the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241449/python-memory-error-in-making-dataframe) suggests that the memory error raise because the PC do not have enough memory, but I'm pretty sure I have enough ram for this data.
3. In [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910947/memoryerror-unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-118-840983-and-data-type-flo), the author get memory error trying to read a huge csv, and the solution is to read data by piece. I understand that I can do the same, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to solve this problem

Here are my code:

```
import csv
import itertools
import pandas as pd

colname= ["id","attachmentPath",...(20 other column names),"eventid"]

reader = csv.reader(open(r'test.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1"), quotechar='"',delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=False, escapechar='\\')

# read full sample
records = []
for record in itertools.islice(reader,1,77058860): # 77058860 is the length of the csv
    records.append(record)

df = pd.DataFrame(records(reader,1,77058860): columns=colname)

statapath = r'stata_output.dta'
df.to_stata(statapath, version=117, write_index=False)
```

Comment: can you not read directly to dataframe with `pd.read_csv()`

Comment: Because I also want to read a smaller random sample from it, so i will need the loop as defined in "for record in itertools.islice(reader,1,77058860)"

Answer (score 4):

I think your data set is too big for the amount of RAM.  In a 2017 blog post, Wes McKinney (creator of Pandas), noted that:

> To put it simply, we weren't thinking about analyzing 100 GB or 1 TB datasets in 2011. Nowadays, **my rule of thumb for pandas is that you should have 5 to 10 times as much RAM as the size of your dataset.** So if you have a 10 GB dataset, you should really have about 64, preferably 128 GB of RAM if you want to avoid memory management problems. This comes as a shock to users who expect to be able to analyze datasets that are within a factor of 2 or 3 the size of their computer's RAM. [emphasis in McKinney's original document]

Source: https://wesmckinney.com/blog/apache-arrow-pandas-internals/

You would probably need to process the data set in chunks.  Here are a couple ways that may reduce memory requirements, depending on the data set:

- convert low-cardinality data to Categorical
- use lowest-size numerical types (e.g., int64 to int8)

More info here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/scale.html

Comment: I see. I have checked my memory usage, it's near 95%. I guess it's also because I read in the csv as a list first (the list named records), which takes more than 25gb memory. anyway I will do this in chunks. Thank you for the explanation